# Upgrading SQLAlchemy from 0.9.7 to 1.3.11 and result obj is immutable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an application that I'm updating the SQLAlchemy version on. It was 0.9.7 and I want it to be 1.3.11. Before, SQLAlchemy would return a KeyedTuple object. Now the result is a sqlalchemy.util._collections.result which is immutable.

In new versions of SQLAlchemy, is it possible to somehow revert to the previous return type? I have a legacy code base, and I do not want to have to go through it all and update it.

Comment: The result tuples being non-immutable [was considered a bug and fixed](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/changelog/changelog_10.html#change-8dff32ea855329842148a57ea75d4663), so it's highly unlikely that it's revertable without jumping through some major hoops. What are the reasons for you to upgrade your legacy applications dependencies?

Comment: @IljaEverilä that closes that door for me. Make this an answer and I'll accept.